# Simple Truffle tests timeout "before all" hook: prepare suite

Tags: truffle, truffle-test, truffle-config

I'm trying to write my first tests for truffle, but I run in a timeout each time I want to execute the tests.

> Error: Timeout of 120000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

Contract deployment with `truffle deploy` to ganache and a parity node works fine, but when I run `truffle test`, truffle hangs for 2min and then runs into a timeout:

```
C:\Development\solidity>truffle test
Using network 'development'.

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.

  Contract: MyContract
    1) "before all" hook: prepare suite

  0 passing (2m)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: MyContract
       "before all" hook: prepare suite:
     Error: Timeout of 120000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (C:\Development\solidity\test\first-tests.js)
```

`truffle test` run fine without any tests (`0 passing (1ms)`), but as soon as I create a test-file with a contract() as described in [the docs](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript) truffle does not respond for 2 minutes, then runs into the timeout error shown above.

My test file in `test/my_test.js`:

```
const MyContract = artifacts.require("MyContract")

contract("MyContract", async () => {
  it("count should be zero after deployment", async () => {
    MyContract.deployed().then(instance => {
      assert.equal(0, 0)
    })
  })
})
```

My `truffle-config.js`:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider")

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      provider: new HDWalletProvider('aa bb cc .. xx yy zz', 'http://127.0.0.1:7545'),
      network_id: 5777,
    },
  },

  mocha: { enableTimeouts: false },
  compilers: { solc: {} },
}
```

Am I missing some important configuration used for running the tests? or why does it run into a timeout? If there's another error causing this timeout, is there a way to debug this in more detail to get a better error description?

The post I found [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19641/how-to-set-the-timeout-for-truffle-tests-before-block) addresses problems with contract deployments that took too long, but my contract is deploy within 10 seconds, so that doesn't seem to be the same problem here.

Things I tried:

- Updating my `truffle-config.js` to include `mocha: { enableTimeouts: false }` as suggested didn't change anything, still same behaviour.
- Create an empty project and start from scratch. Same Behaviour.
  ( I did `truffle init`, write contract, add to migrations, add truffle-config, add test-file, run `truffle build|deploy|test`.)

Any hint on what to do to get my very basic test working would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You could add `mocha: {enableTimeouts: false}` in your Truffle configuration file (`truffle.js` or `truffle-config.js`), but the problem is probably in one of your migration scripts (located under `migrations`). You'd wanna check those, and possibly "disable" them when `network == "development"` (or fix them in a different manner).

Comment: Try to create them in the test itself, so to begin with, your problem should then occur in the `it` and not in some "mysterious" `before`. BTW, `contract` takes a regular function, so you can (and should) remove that `async` in there.

Comment: Which version of Truffle are you using?

Comment: I have version 5.0.31

Comment: I recommend trying 4.1.15.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an issue in a way you use **HDWalletProvider** when configuring `development` network in `truffle-config.js`.

You should add it like:

```
provider: () => new HDWalletProvider('your mnemonic', 'http://127.0.0.1:7545')
```

For me, it helped. Additional info can be found [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/1022).

Comment: I've updated my answer, since I could solve the problem on my computer. Try it, @JackO'neill

Comment: That was it, it works now. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: A bit of explanation. Why it's related to timeout. Testing seems to use a lot of connections now and previous Truffle provider setting was reaching the limit of the provider. Then requests were not successful and test was waiting for an answer that was not going to arrive, hence the timeout. New way to define provider enables more parallel connections (up to some point I guess).

Answer (score 0):

`npm uninstall -g truffle`

`npm install -g truffle@5.1.10` (always got me back on track)